# Gitlab CI merge rules changes with if condition

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have multiple similar jobs:
<sub>which all have a similar condition of running only when brach is equal to default branch, and also every job should only run on that job's specific changes:</sub>

```
job1:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      changes:
        - 'test.py'
        - 'main.py'

job2:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      changes:
        - 'important.txt'
        - 'even_more_important.txt'

job3:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      changes:
        - 'somefile.md'
```

I was wondering if it's possible to get rid of repetitive lines, something like this (or even something more concise...):

```
.default_job:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'

job1:
  extends: .default_job
  rules: 
      changes:
        - 'test.py'
        - 'main.py'
job2:
  extends: .default_job
  rules: 
      changes:
        - 'important.txt'
        - 'even_more_important.txt'
job3:
  # ....
```

so that I'd need to only define specific changes to that job, and automatically get the other condition (only run on default branch) inherited?
I already tried merging but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you trying to apply this to _ALL_ your jobs? If so, maybe consider using `workflow:rules:` which applies to the pipeline as a whole, instead of at the job level. That is: you will only have a pipeline if `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH`. Each of your jobs can still have their own independent rules.

Comment: @sytech sadly, I have other stages jobs which should always run. With the workflows rule they do not run.

Comment: [`!reference`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags) could help maybe